# Sound is unbalanced on both speakers ! I am hearing loud sound from the left and low sound from the right speaker

Tags: sound, home-theatre

I have checked with other headphones,and my small 2:1 home theatre also complies the existence of the problem.

Moreover when I check my sound system through Pulseaudio "test sound" utility, I can see there are six buttons shown, whereas I should only have lest and right buttons as I have 2:1 home theatre (connected on the rear audio port) and a normal headphone (connected on the front side).

I also have jackd installed and configured to run along-with pulseaudio.

On the Screenshot you can see Jack Sink is working with five output ports where I should only have Front Left and front right.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the image tag facility instead of using "img src"?

Comment: @vasa1: thanks for the advice. Can you help me regarding to my problem ?